# Noflo .fbp array initiallizer

Tags: noflo

I'm using noflo and am trying to send an array as an initiallizer. There doesn't seem to be a supported (or at least documented) way to do this.

I'm currently using:

```
'["Kicker"]' -> IN Nodes(strings/ParseJson)
'{"in":"go!"}' -> IN Config(strings/ParseJson)

Nodes() OUT -> NODES MyComponent(noflotest/Universe)
Config OUT -> CONFIG MyComponent()
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently arrays and other complicated data structures are not supported in the `.fbp` syntax. There is [a feature request about this](https://github.com/noflo/fbp/issues/10).

Right now you have three options:

- If FBP parser accepts your string (see the [matching rules](https://github.com/noflo/fbp/blob/master/grammar/fbp.peg#L161)), you can first send it to the `strings/ParseJson` component to turn it to the appropriate data structure
- Reading the value from a JSON or YAML file and passing it through the appropriate parser component
- Converting your graph to the [JSON graph format](http://noflojs.org/documentation/json/)